# Почему программа выдаёт только жёлтый экран, без картинки корабля?

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings=Settings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Aliene Invasion")
    ship = Ship(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()
        ship.blitme()
run_game()
```

```py
import pygame
class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
         self.screen=screen
         self.image=pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
         self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
         self.screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
         self.rect.centerx=self.screen_rect.centerx
         self.rect.bottom=self.screen_rect.bottom
    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

```py
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width=1000
        self.screen_height=600
        self.bg_color=(230,230,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не в том месте `pygame.display.flip()`

```
import sys
import pygame

#from settings import Settings
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width  = 1000
        self.screen_height =  600
        self.bg_color      = (230, 230, 0)

#from ship import Ship
class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
         self.screen = screen
         self.image  = pygame.image.load("im.png")            # ("images/ship.bmp")
         self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
         self.screen_rect  = screen.get_rect()
         self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
         self.rect.bottom  = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Aliene Invasion")
    ship = Ship(screen)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
#        pygame.display.flip()                     # ---
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()                      # +++

run_game()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]